# QuerySet with GenericRelation return 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a model **Console**.
It has a GenericForeignKey: **configuration**.
I have serveral model as:

- configuration_A
- configuration_B

On each of these models I have:

```
 console = GenericRelation(
    'device.Console', related_query_name='A', object_id_field='configuration')
```

Obviously with different related_query_name.

I want to query my console model and filter it by configuration, here is what I am doing:
`my_queryset = Console.objects.filter(A__id=random_id)`

I know for sure that 'random_id' exists.

When I want to print the result the query or 'my_queryset.query' I got:

> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Do you have any idea of how to fix it or even debug it ?

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I delete:

> object_id_field='configuration'

from my genericRelation and it seems to work now !